# Getting char in string and replacing it with StringBuilder producing blank char

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do is get the value from a EditText, get the currently selected number, plus 1 to that number, reinsert it to the string then update the edit text box so lets just say I have an int

```
123456
```

and want to get the value of 3 and then plus 1 to it.

the code I have written is here:

```
//Get Current Text in the EditText
number = currentEdit.getText().toString();

//New String Builder
StringBuilder up = new StringBuilder(number);

//Get Current Selected value, for stack overflow purpose ive hard coded 1
int selectedNumber = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(1));

//if the current item +1 is greater than 9, change it to 0 and so on
if(selectedNumber++ > 9){
   selectedNumber = 0;
 }else{
     selectedNumber++;
  }
  //Replace current string with new updated value
  up.setCharAt(1, (char)selectedNumber);
  //reinsert it to the edit text
  currentEdit.setText(up.toString());
```

Imagine this is the EditText;

before: 123456

after: 12 456

Comment: Replace `Character.getNumericValue(...)` with `Character.digit(..., 10)`, and replace `(char)selectedNumber` with `Character.forDigit(selectedNumber, 10)`.

Comment: "want to get the value of 3 and then plus 1 to it." Why don't I see that in your example "before" and "after"? (input and output by the way)

Comment: Also you seem to have a special case for 9, so please explain that with a separate example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(char)selectedNumber` does not get the character representation of the extracted digit. It will return the ASCII character whose number is `selectedNumber`. To get the character representation, you can use `Character.forDigit(selectedNumber, 10)`:

```
up.setCharAt(1, Character.forDigit(selectedNumber, 10));
```

Also note that in your code, the `selectedNumber` is incremented twice. You can replace the check with:

```
if (selectedNumber == 9) {
```

Comment: amazing! Yeah I forgot to change to ++ part, thank you! Ill vote it correct in 6 minutes.